# Can you recover objects from debug mode in R-Studio?

Tags: r, object, debugging, environment-variables, recover

Last night, after some exhausting debugging, I finished a new function that ran little over 5 hours and was to save into an object.

```
myResult <- myComputation(myArgument)
```

Something like this. Unfortunately, the function was still in debug mode, so after finishing without errors myResult remains nonexistent.

Is there a way to save/recover objects from browsing/debugging mode?

Comment: Might be important that I did not close R Studio since but I did stop debugging.

Comment: It is not possible after you have quit the debugger, but while being in debugging you can use the answer i have provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

If you have an existing variable in the global environment you can use the `variableName<<-` operator. Alternative use the `assign(variableNameAsString, ObjectToSave, globalenv())` where `variableNameAsString` should be replaced by the name you want to save your output under, and `ObjectToSave` is the object to save. This will save your object after the debug session is quit.

Very quick example:

```
x  <- 3
#dummy function that someone did not remember to return stuff from
xfunc <- function(x){ 
   x <- x * 3
   assign("cookieMonster", x, globalenv())
   browser()
   cat("hello world")
}
x2 <- xfunc(x)
x2 
[1] NULL
cookieMonster 
[1] 9
```